# How do you view HTML entities in Firefox Developer Edition's inspector

Tags: firefox, html-entities, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

Firefox Developer Edition was showing HTML entities (e.g.  ) in the DOM inspector. For some reason it stopped. I've created a fresh Firefox profile but I still can't see them. Anyone got any ideas how to view them in Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

@luke-h I'm fairly certain it makes sense to piggyback https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1256756

I just did.